# My Flutter "Generate PDF" button is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a Flutter application where I need to generate a PDF when a button is pressed. However, the "Generate PDF" button is not functioning as expected. I'm encountering the following error in the console:

this is my error console :

> E/flutter ( 7975): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no
> indices are valid: 0 E/flutter ( 7975): #0      Uint8List.[]
> (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:2271:7) E/flutter (
> 7975): #1      InputBuffer.[]
> (package:image/src/util/input_buffer.dart:44:39) E/flutter ( 7975): #2
> JpegData.validate
> (package:image/src/formats/jpeg/jpeg_data.dart:64:17) E/flutter (
> 7975): #3      JpegDecoder.isValidFile
> (package:image/src/formats/jpeg_decoder.dart:18:50) E/flutter ( 7975):
> #4      findDecoderForData (package:image/src/formats/formats.dart:116:11) E/flutter ( 7975): #5
> new MemoryImage (package:pdf/src/widgets/image_provider.dart:101:24)
> E/flutter ( 7975): #6      CetakinvoicePage._generatePDF. (package:smta/cetakinvoicepage.dart:421:22) E/flutter (
> 7975): #7      Page.postProcess
> (package:pdf/src/widgets/page.dart:142:21) E/flutter ( 7975): #8
> Document.save (package:pdf/src/widgets/document.dart:130:14) E/flutter
> ( 7975): #9      CetakinvoicePage._generatePDF
> (package:smta/cetakinvoicepage.dart:442:39) E/flutter ( 7975):
>  E/flutter ( 7975):

this is my code :

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class CetakinvoicePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Your existing content here...
                Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/logosgntulisan.png',
                                      width: 120,
                                    ),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Image.asset(
                                          'assets/images/barcodedummy.png',
                                          width: 150,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                                        const Text(
                                          'SG10202312060001',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child: const Divider(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    thickness: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  const Text(
                                    'PT SINERGI GULA NUSANTARA',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ]
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
                // Button to trigger PDF generation
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _generatePDF(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Generate PDF'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Function to generate PDF
  Future<void> _generatePDF(BuildContext context) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();


    // Add content to the PDF
    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Row(
          children: [
            pw.Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
              ],
            ),
            pw.Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                pw.Text(
                  'Waktu Masuk',
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: PdfColors.black,
                    fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                pw.Text(
                  '14-12/2023 19.00',
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: PdfColors.black,
                    fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                pw.Image(
                  pw.MemoryImage(
                    // Convert your image to bytes (you might need to change this part)
                    // For example: (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/truktebugambar.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List()
                    Uint8List.fromList([/* your image bytes go here */]),
                  ),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 120,
                ),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ));

    // Get the application documents directory
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create the PDF file
    final file = File('${directory.path}/example.pdf');
    await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

    // Open the PDF using a PDF viewer
    OpenFile.open(file.path);
  }
}
```

I have tried to address this issue by including the necessary code for generating the PDF, but it seems there's an error related to the MemoryImage. I suspect it's related to loading the image for the PDF, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Any help or guidance on fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message seems to refer to a Memory Image (probably the one you're trying to create in your pdf method without any parameter). See the comment in your code block saying :

> /* your image bytes go here */

Try commenting your pw.Image() block until you put something in the Uint8List.fromList(), or change your pw.MemoryImage for something like this :

```
pw.MemoryImage(
      (await rootBundle.load('images/mylogo.webp'))
          .buffer
          .asUint8List(),
    )
```